# AJAX JSON data retrieve (Portlet+Liferay+JSON+Spring)

Tags: java, ajax, spring, liferay, portlet

What I want to do is, just post data to server and get data from server by using JSON & AJAX.
I am converting legacy non AJAX project to AJAX. It is a liferay portlet spring ibatis jquery project. Form submission was success and I could not be able to retrieve data from server as JSON. I used [spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/)
sample to learn jackson for JSON. It was very easy no need me to even think about JSON.
I just copy-paste two jar files in my build path and annotate @ResponseBody to my method. But still response is full html page. Why?

JSP code here

```
   <portlet:actionURL var="formAction">
        <portlet:param name="action" value="submit"/>
    </portlet:actionURL>


    <c:set var="formPortletNamespace">form<portlet:namespace/></c:set>

    <form:form method="post" action="${formAction}" commandName="uiState" id="${formPortletNamespace}" cssClass="travelInsurancePortletForm jqCustomStyle" autocomplete="off">
        <% /* Selected action as a parameter */ %>
        <input type="hidden" name="portletAction" id="portletAction"/>

        <form:hidden path="quote.quotingWebApp" />
```

JS code here.This code submit the form to server

```
function doPortletAction(actionName) {
   jQuery('form#form<portlet:namespace/> input#portletAction').val(actionName); 

   jQuery('form#form<portlet:namespace/> input#<portlet:namespace/>-posted').val('true');
//jQuery('form#form<portlet:namespace/>').submit();


jQuery.ajax({
    url: jQuery('#form<portlet:namespace/>').attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    data: jQuery('#form<portlet:namespace/>').serialize(),
    success: onAjaxSubmitReturn
});
```

}

Controller coding

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController{

    @ActionMapping(params="portletAction=myAction")
    public @ResponseBody UiState myAction( 
            PortletSession session, 
            ActionResponse response, 
            @RequestParam(value="endDate", required=false) Date endDate,
            @ModelAttribute("uiState") UiState requestUiState,
            BindingResult errors,
            ModelMap mm) throws Exception {

    UiState uiState=new UiState ();
        return uiState;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what UiState is, but its probably responding with a "text/html" content type, which is the default.  You'll need to declare your response type as "application/json" in your `myAction` method.

Comment: thanks.I could be able to load JSON data from spring controller by using.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Action` phase does not produce any output. It always goes to `Render` phase. So this code wouldn't work anyway.

For second, as of Spring `4.1` it [doesn't support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7344) `@ResponseBody` for portlets yet. It is planning in `4.2`, but it might not be there as well.

So what you need is to use either `@RenderMapping` or `@ResourceMapping` (JSR-286/Portlet 2.0 only).

The most natural way is to use `@ResourceMapping`. Code will look like the following:

```
@ResourceMapping("myAction")
public void myAction(
        PortletSession session,
        ResourceResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value="endDate", required=false) Date endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("uiState") UiState requestUiState,
        BindingResult errors,
        ModelMap mm) throws Exception {

    UiState uiState = new UiState ();

    //TODO extra logic

    //explicitly set JSON as response type
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    //write JSON into output
    response.getWriter().write(serializeJSON(uiState));
}
```

Whereis `serializeJSON` is utility method by your choice.

Sample implementation is the following (based on [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) serializer):

```
public static String serializeJSON(Object o) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(o);
}
```

**Note**: you need to use this snippet on your JSP(s):

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="formAction" id="myAction"/>
```